# Learning C, segfailt confusion

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I've been trying to teach myself c over spring break and it's been a lot more challenging than i had anticipated! I've made some good progress, however i seem to have hit a snag. I've been writing my own implementation of a doubly linked list. After about eight hours of plugging along, I've got what seems to be a fairly coherent program. The compiler is giving me the all clear ahead, and i've successfully built the project multiple times. Now, i started programming in java; so to my mind the aforementioned assurances constitute an ironclad guarantee of success. However C seems to c things differently (pardon the pun)! When i attempt to run my program, i get a 'segfault' run-time error. I've spent some time reading up on this error, and (as im sure i'm about to be informed) it's an issue of memory mis-allocation. I've tried to debug, but no matter where i set my breakpoints i cant seem to preempt the error. I'm in a bit of a quandry, and i'd really appreciate any insights y'all might have to offer me! I apologize for the monolith of text i've just scrawled out... and i'll try to keep the post script brief. Here's a rough outline of my setup:

- NetBeans 6.8 IDE with Cygwin environment
- Currently running windows 7 x64

I'll post my code below, but certainly don't feel obligated to go sifting through it. What i'm really hoping for is a few suggestions on how to handle segfaults in general. I get the feeling i'll be seeing them a lot, and i'd like to develop a strategy for troubleshooting this particular issue.

Thanks in advance! without you guys i'd be up a serious creek!

main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include"dll.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    VECT coord1;
    coord1->x = 0.0012345;
    coord1->y = 0.012345;
    coord1->z = 0.12345;

    LIST coords = init_list();
    list_add(coords, coord1);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

dll.c (doubley linked list source file)

```
#include "dll.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include"dll.h"

LIST init_list() {
    LIST list = (LIST) malloc(sizeof (struct list));
    list->length = 0;
    list->first = NULL;
    list->last = NULL;
    list->destructor = free;
    return list;
}

LIST_ITR list_iterator(LIST list, bool from_front) {
    LIST_ITR iter = (LIST_ITR) malloc(sizeof (struct list_itr));
    if (from_front) {
        iter->current = list->first;
    } else if (!from_front) {
        iter->current = list->last;
    } else return NULL;
    iter->started = 0;
    return iter;
}

void list_add(LIST list, VECT coords) {
    NODE node = (NODE) malloc(sizeof (struct node));
    node->coord_vector = coords;

    if (list->first == NULL) {
        node->prev = NULL;
        node->next = NULL;
        list->first = node;
        list->last = node;
    } else {
        list->last->next = node;
        node->prev = list->last;
        node->next = NULL;
        list->last = node;
    }
    list->length++;
}

VECT list_itr_current(LIST_ITR iter) {
    if (iter->started && iter->current != NULL)
        return iter->current->coord_vector;
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

VECT list_itr_next(LIST_ITR iter) {
    if (!iter->started && iter->current != NULL) {
        iter->started = 1;
        return iter->current->coord_vector;
    }
    if (iter->current != NULL) {
        iter->current = iter->current->next;
        return list_itr_current(iter);
    }
    return NULL;
}

VECT list_prev(LIST_ITR iter) {
    if (!iter->started && iter->current != NULL) {
        iter->started = 1;
        return iter->current->coord_vector;
    }
    if (iter->current != NULL) {
        iter->current = iter->current->prev;
        return list_itr_current(iter);
    }
    return NULL;
}

VECT list_get_first(LIST list) {
    return list->first->coord_vector;
}

VECT list_get_last(LIST list) {
    return list->last->coord_vector;
}

VECT list_pop(LIST list) {
    NODE last = list->last;
    if (last == NULL) return NULL;

    if (list->first == list->last) {
        list->first = NULL;
        list->last = NULL;
    } else {
        list->last = last->prev;
        last->prev->next = NULL;
    }

    VECT data = last->coord_vector;
    free(last);
    list->length--;
    return data;
}

VECT list_poll(LIST list) {
    NODE first = list->first;

    if (first == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if (list->first == list->last) {
        list->first = NULL;
        list->last = NULL;
    } else {
        list->first = first->next;
        first->next->prev = NULL;
    }

    VECT data = first->coord_vector;
    free(first);
    list->length--;
    return data;
}

void list_remove(LIST list, bool from_front) {
    VECT data;
    if (from_front)
        data = list_poll(list);
    else if (!from_front)
        data = list_pop(list);
    else return;
    list->destructor(data);
}

void destroy_list(LIST list) {
    NODE current = list->first;
    NODE next;
    while (current != NULL) {
        next = current->next;
        list->destructor(current->coord_vector);
        free(current);
        current = next;
    }
    free(list);
}
```

dll.h (doubley linked list header file)

```
#include<stdbool.h>

#ifndef _DLL_H
#define _DLL_H

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    /* A C implementation of a doubly-linked list. Contains void pointer values.
   Can be used as a LIFO stack of FIFO queue. */

#define FRONT 0
#define BACK 1

struct vector{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

typedef struct vector* VECT;

struct node{
        VECT    coord_vector;
    struct node* next;
    struct node* prev;
};

typedef struct node* NODE;

struct list{
    int length;
    NODE first;
    NODE last;
    void (*destructor)(void*);
};

typedef struct list * LIST;

struct list_itr{
    NODE current;
    char started;
};

typedef struct list_itr * LIST_ITR;

//Initializes the list
LIST init_list();

//initializes the list iterator
LIST_ITR list_iterator(LIST list, bool from_front);

//append element to end
void list_add(LIST list, VECT coords);

//Gets the data stored in the first item of the list or NULL if the list is empty
VECT list_get_first(LIST list);

//Gets the data stored in the last item of the list or NULL if the list is empty
VECT list_get_last(LIST list);

//LIFO pop: remove element and return data
VECT list_pop(LIST list);

//FIFO poll: remove element and return data
VECT list_poll(LIST list);

//Deletes element and frees memory
void list_remove(LIST list, bool from_front);

//Delete list and free all memory
void destroy_list(LIST list);

//returns the data of the element pointed to by current
VECT list_itr_current(LIST_ITR list_itr);

//Increments the index of current by 1 and returns the data stored there
VECT list_itr_next(LIST_ITR list_itr);

//Decrements the index of current by 1 and returns the data stored there
VECT list_prev(LIST_ITR list_itr);

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  /* _DLL_H */
```

Comment: You should use a debugger to figure out where your problem occurs and narrow it down.

Comment: You can't "handle a segfault", you fix the bug. I see a ton of code, but no mention as to where the segfault occurs.

Comment: With respect to Ed's comment, it is useful to throw printf statements every where when you are just learning to code with C - or learn to use a debugger.

Comment: In addition to the useful comments above mine, I'll throw in something useless: naming your files "dll.[ch]" is not a good idea, due to the possibility of confusion that can have (since dll is an accepted and understood term that means nothing in regards to double linked lists).

Comment: Thanks for the response guys. It's not that i haven't tried to debug, it's that the debugger never seems to kick in. I've got breakpoints every which way, but no matter how i configure things the debug session runs strait into the segfault. I'm going to try adding some printf's to see if i can narrow things down. I'll update as soon as i have more info. Again, thanks!!

Comment: I just tried a printf as the first line in my main... same thing. The program terminated before the line was executed. To my mind that screams compile error, but the IDE isn't showing any. Could it be related to my use of windows as opposed to linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should build your code with -Wall flag to compiler.  At compile time it will then print:

main.c:9:15: warning: ‘coord1’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

This points you to the problem.
coord1 is a pointer type, that you assign to, but coord1 has no memory backing it until it is initialized.  In the following snippet coord1 is initialized by allocating memory to store it's components.  This gets rid of the segfault.

```
VECT coord1 = NULL;

coord1 = (VECT)malloc(sizeof(struct vector));
if (NULL == coord1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory!\n");
    exit(1);
}

coord1->x = 0.0012345;
coord1->y = 0.012345;
coord1->z = 0.12345;
```

In general, segfaults happen when a program accesses memory that the operating system has not allocated to it.  Unintialized pointers usually point to address zero, which is not allocated to any program.  Always use gcc -Wall  when compiling, this will many times point to these potential problems.  Helped me find it right away.

Also, you could have declared your VECT type to be typedef struct vector (a non-pointer type).

```
VECT coord1;
VECT* v_coord1 = &coord1;
v_coord1->x = 0.0012345;
v_coord1->y = 0.012345;
v_coord1->z = 0.12345;`
```

Also, variable naming conventions can help here as well.

```
struct vector{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
 };

typedef struct vector VECT;
typedef struct vector* pVECT;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I've been scratching my head over this for the past 48 hrs. I can't tell you how much i appreciate the explanation!!